# Why are Facebook and Pinterest widgets not showing?

Tags: html, css, facebook, widget, pinterest

In my introductory web and interactive media class we are having trouble trying to figure out why these two widgets won't display. Can anyone tell me why and how to fix it. Please be specific and this is introductory so a simple solution please. I understand HTML and CSS better than most in my class, but I'm no expert.

```
<div class="fb-page" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/PSU.GIT" data-hide-cover="false" data-show-facepile="true" data-show-posts="false"><div class="fb-xfbml-parse-ignore"><blockquote cite="https://www.facebook.com/PSU.GIT"><a href="https://www.facebook.com/PSU.GIT">PSU Graphics &amp; Imaging Technologies</a></blockquote></div></div>


<a data-pin-do="embedUser" href="http://www.pinterest.com/GetCr8tiveToday/"></a>
```

```
 <script type="text/javascript" async defer src="//assets.pinterest.com/js/pinit.js"></script>
```

Comment: Have you include the Facebook javascript code?

Comment: Could be because of where you are calling the script tag. The way both of these should work: you add the respective script tags on the page so facebook and pintrest can load in their own javascript which will then populate the placeholders (the <div> and the <a>)

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to include the JavaScript SDK on your page once, ideally right after the opening  tag.

```js
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.3";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
```

2. Then place this code where ever you want to display the widget.

```html
<div class="fb-page" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/PSU.GIT" data-hide-cover="false" data-show-facepile="true" data-show-posts="false"><div class="fb-xfbml-parse-ignore"><blockquote cite="https://www.facebook.com/PSU.GIT"><a href="https://www.facebook.com/PSU.GIT">PSU Graphics &amp; Imaging Technologies</a></blockquote></div></div>
```